# Correlation between poisson and normal

Tags: probability

X is a normally distributed variable with mean 4 and standard deviation 2. Y is a poisson variable with parameter 6 independent of X. Z = X+Y. What is the correlation between Y and Z?

So far I have Cov(Z,Y) = E[ZY] -E[Z]E[Y]

=20 + 6 - 10*6 = -34. Which implies a correlation of -34/sqrt(6) which is less than -1.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I edited the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correlation of approx. $-14.5$ is indeed a problem!
I think there may be something wrong with your computation of the covariance:
If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $Z=X+Y$, then
\begin{align*}
\text{E}[ZY]-\text{E}[Z]\text{E}[Y]&=\text{E}[XY+Y^2]-\text{E}[X+Y]\text{E}[Y]\\
&=\text{E}[XY]+\text{E}[Y^2]-\text{E}[X]\text{E}[Y]-(\text{E}[Y])^2\\
&=\text{E}[X]\text{E}[Y]+\text{E}[Y^2]-\text{E}[X]\text{E}[Y]-(\text{E}[Y])^2&\text{($X$ and $Y$ independent)}\\
&=\text{E}[Y^2]-(\text{E}[Y])^2\\
&=\text{Var}[Y].\\
\end{align*}

EDIT: Furthermore, it seems that, in your computation of the correlation, you divide the covariance by the standard deviation of $Y$ only. The correlation coefficient of $Y$ and $Z$ is computed as follows $$\rho_{Z,Y}=\frac{\text{Cov}[Z,Y]}{\sqrt{\text{Var}[Z]\text{Var[Y]}}}.$$

Comment: @Did But the question does compute the covariance wrong, which is part of what is going wrong in the computation of correlation.

Comment: Yes, but they were also calling correlation the covariance (this is corrected now). Comment withdrawn. And the Edit in your answer is most welcome, if you ask me... (+1.)

Comment: @JuhoKokkala Yes.